# Why does the contents of this function freeze the View? iOS Swift 2 Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

**Context:** Im building an app that saves a persons name & age in persistent storage then displays it on a label in a new View Controller(SecondViewController) when they re-open the app. Essentially Im trying to achieve a welcome back message that is presented through a label.

This code below is setting up myName to equal the user input from the text field, my text field is called nameEntry

**Code for the Declaration of myName:** NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(nameEntry.text, forKey: "myName")

**THIS CODE BELOW** is hopefully going to take the user to the SecondViewController when the value for key myName is not equal to nothing(nil). **Something within this function freezes the view**, the segue identifier is called firstToSecond.

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
 if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("myName") != nil
 {

    performSegueWithIdentifier("firstToSecond", sender: nil)
 }
 }
```

Comment: Can you isolate it to `performSegueWithId...`?

Comment: When I put performSegueWithIdentifier("firstToSecond", sender: nil) inside the function I have for the save button i get a freeze after button click.

Comment: Console:   2016-02-24 20:26:49.031 24feb[8016:500129] Unknown class SecondViewController in Interface Builder file.
Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x10a8bb308) to '_4feb.SecondViewController' (0x1091ba3f0).
(lldb)

Comment: Thread 1: signal SIGABART    --Shown on the last line of this code that is passing info to the other view controller--- if segue.identifier == "firstToSecond"
        {
            //pass the information
            let sVC = segue.destinationViewController
                as! SecondViewController }

Comment: So your storyboard scene says that the class for the second view controller is `SecondViewController` but no such class exists in your app.  Check for typing errors

Comment: Fixed: There was a problem with file structure the SecondViewController.swift file was corrupted somehow, thank you all for the help. If your interested...I can perform a segue on viewDidAppear but I only want to run the segue if the user has already input something into the text fields i.e. a returning user. My new problem or question is how do I check for the values in the apps memory and decide to run the segue if it exists and if not allow the app to open as normal(not a returning user)?

Comment: @Nemty what memory are you talking about? a variable?

Comment: To echo/reiterate Vasnath, are you asking how to check a variable that you made? If so, then NSUserDefaults is the answer. Or, do you mean memory as in the actual memory pertaining to the OS as a whole?